# The height of list-view in card-view is changing after scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-cardview

I am using card-view which contains list-view. The list-view item count should be changed according to user's input so I set the list-view height as wrap_content. Everything is normal until user scrolls but after scrolling the height of list-view or card-view is changing.

[image: Before Scroll]
[image: After Scroll]

Here are my xml and card-view adapter code blocks;

Card-view adapter

```
public class RoundItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoundItemAdapter.RoundItemViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Round> mRounds;
private Context context;

public RoundItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Round> rounds){
    mRounds = rounds;
    this.context = context;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public RoundItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.round_item, parent, false);
    RoundItemViewHolder roundItemViewHolder = new RoundItemViewHolder(view);
    return roundItemViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RoundItemViewHolder roundItemViewHolder, int position) {
    Round currentItem = mRounds.get(position);

    roundItemViewHolder.mTextViewTitle.setText("Round: " + currentItem.number);

    MatchItemAdapter matchItemAdapter = new MatchItemAdapter(context, R.layout.match_item, currentItem.matches);
    roundItemViewHolder.mListViewRound.setAdapter(matchItemAdapter);
    matchItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mRounds.size();
}



public static class RoundItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView mTextViewTitle;
    public ListView mListViewRound;
    public RoundItemViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mTextViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_rounds_title);
        mListViewRound = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listView_rounds);
      }
    }}
```

Xml for card-view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
android:layout_margin="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_rounds_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_rounds"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Match-item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_player_home_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView_vs"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_player_away_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_gray_24dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_gray_24dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_player_home_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_vs"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_player_home_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_vs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="vs"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_player_home_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView_player_away_name"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_player_home_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_player_home_name" />
```

Comment: Can you please attach the xml for R.layout.match_item ?

Comment: @VishalArora how can I attach R.layout.match_item?

Comment: Just as you added the xml for cardview

Comment: I added match-item.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing listview size programmatically. First I set height of listview as 55dp(One line's height in list view is 55dp) in card-view.xml file. After I changed onBindViewHolder method in RoundItemAdapter class. onBindViewHolder method is like that after changes.

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RoundItemViewHolder roundItemViewHolder, int position) {
    Round currentItem = mRounds.get(position);

    roundItemViewHolder.mTextViewTitle.setText("Round: " + currentItem.number);

    MatchItemAdapter matchItemAdapter = new MatchItemAdapter(context, R.layout.match_item, currentItem.matches);
    roundItemViewHolder.mListViewRound.setAdapter(matchItemAdapter);
    matchItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)roundItemViewHolder.mListViewRound.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = lp.height * mRounds.get(position).matches.size();
    roundItemViewHolder.mListViewRound.setLayoutParams(lp);

}
```

I have also tried many changes in the XML file to solve this problem, but I did not. I believe there should be another way to solve this problem by just modifying the xml files. I share this solution because I saw that there are others who are facing with the same problem in my searches on the Internet. Those who have a different solution can also answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `layout_height` constraint of the `CardView` and the `ConstraintLayout` from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`.

Xml for card-view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
android:layout_margin="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_rounds_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_rounds"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Match-item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_player_home_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView_vs"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_player_away_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_gray_24dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_gray_24dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_player_home_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_vs"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_player_home_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_vs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:text="vs"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_player_home_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView_player_away_name"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_player_home_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_player_home_name" />
```

Comment: When I change layout_height as wrap-content only first item of list-view is appear.

Comment: Ok. Then please attach your R.layout.match_item xml as @VishalArora suggested

Comment: I added match-item.xml